# Операционная система Linux

Tags: linux

Линукс - 4% пользователей ей пользуются как основной ОС на настольных ПК. Я давно хочу перейти на Линукс, учусь на программиста и также увлекаюсь музыкой (слушаю, начинающий аудиофил). Так в чем суть этого вопроса, как можно перейти на Линукс с виндовс? У меня задаётся много вопросов по типу - а что если? А кто поможет? Кто объяснит? Буду очень благодарен!

Comment: Во-первых, Linux — это не операционная система. Во-вторых, как перейти — взять и установить принглянувшийся дистрибутив. В-третьих, поможет и объяснит интернет.

Comment: Начните с выбора дистрибутива. Как по мне, можно начать с операционной системы Ubuntu. Ну нас в компании почти все разработчики (программисты) работают именно на Ubuntu. И не слушайте занудных линуксойдов, которые постоянно пытаются сломать уже сложившийся стереотип, что "Linux - это операционная система, ну та, которая не Windows". Как по мне, так в это вникать обывателю даже не стоит.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Перед тем, как устанавливать операционную систему, лучше сначала проверить ее работу на загрузочном образе `Live CD/USB`. Начинать лучше с *Debian / Ubuntu* - по ним проще всего найти информацию в интернете. Далее можно попробовать различные [окружения рабочего стола](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B0_%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%BE_%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B0) - *да (!!)* выглядеть оно может по-разному. На серверах часто используется *CentOS*, поэтому подойдет в качестве основой системы для программиста / тестировщика / администратора / продвинутого пользователя.

**UPD:** Можно установить `Linux` на флешку. Для этого понадобится две флешки: одна с установочным образом, а вторая - куда устанавливать. Такая флешка лучше `Live USB` тем, что на ней настройки системы сохранятся и не слетают при перезагрузке.

Answer (score 3):

#### предуведомление:

*linux* — это **не** операционная система и тем более **не** «семейство операционных систем» (да, именно так написано в википедии, но это термин для обывателей, а не сведущих в вопросе специалистов). это программа (библиотека, если угодно), выполняющая функции ядра в ряде операционных систем.

наиболее известна из них операционная система *gnu/linux*.

распространяется она в виде *дистрибутивов*, в которые, помимо операционной системы, включается множество пользовательских программ и библиотек.

---

#### основная часть:

при наличии уже работающей операционной системы и отсутствии «свободного» компьютера, пожалуй, наиболее простой и безболезненный вариант «как попробовать» — это воспользоваться подготовленным образом для виртуальной машины.

наиболее популярные программы для запуска виртуальных машин — это *virtualbox* и *vmware*.

подготовленные образы часто можно найти на сайтах дистрибутивов. но на свой страх и риск можно воспользоваться и образами с сайтов-агрегаторов. например, https://www.osboxes.org (для [virtualbox](https://www.osboxes.org/virtualbox-images/) или для [vmware](https://www.osboxes.org/vmware-images/))